# ImportError on newaly production django + apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm in the middle of deploying my django project.
got the wsgi working and now I got importError.

error:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named forms
```

this is the import:

```
from profile.forms import UserRegistrationForm
```

profile is a folder resides in my project dir.
this is the wsgi script I use:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/srv/www/project'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = '/srv/www'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the profile folder?

Comment: yes, an emptry file.
This works on Dev.
the profile folder was out of project directory and I added it in

Comment: no, same import error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work, needed to add project name as prefix.

```
from projectname.profile.forms import <something>
```